# Conditional (ternary) operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that will generate a random color and will set the color state with that color value.

That color state will then be used to set the background color of the div.

Inside the div a have lock/unlock button that will set locked state to true/false;

Now that part I'm having trouble with is using a tenerary operator inside the style element:

what I want it to do is :

if unlock: change color

if lock: dont change color and keep the same one

```js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Pallete({ changeColor }) {
const [locked, setLocked] = useState(false)
  const [color, setColor] = useState(
    "#" + (((1 << 24) * Math.random()) | 0).toString(16)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const randomColor = "#" + (((1 << 24) * Math.random()) | 0).toString(16);
    setColor(randomColor);
  }, [changeColor]);


const lockButton = () =>{
  setLocked(!locked)
}

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        ***style={{ backgroundColor: !locked? color: color }}***
        className="w-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"
      >
        <h1>#FF00FF</h1>
        <button className="btn btn-dark" onClick={lockButton}>UNLOCK</button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: link: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-water-l3oj0

Comment: do you have an error when you try to use ternary condition on style ?

Comment: Do you specifically want information about the ternary operator and why it is not working here, or just a solution that makes the code work?

Comment: @KevinGilbert No it changes the color if unlock and removes color if locked

Answer (score 3):

I change two part of your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(locked){ // check if its locked or not
      const randomColor = "#" + (((1 << 24) * Math.random()) | 0).toString(16);
      setColor(randomColor);
    }
}, [changeColor, locked]); // add locked to watch for
```

You can remove the `!locked ? color : color` part too:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand this is the solution:

```
    useEffect(() => {

            if (!locked) {
               const randomColor = "#" + (((1 << 24) * Math.random()) | 0).toString(16);
               setColor(randomColor);
            }
            }, [changeColor, locked]);
```

and then in the style object set the background to color without ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 ) just like you said ... have you tried ?

```js
<Component style={{background: locked ? '#f00' : 'f0f'}} />
```

Option 2 ) before the Return statement, define the style.

```js
const style = foo ? '...' : '...'
```

```js
<Component style={style} />
```

Comment: I dont think this works. The reason being is because: if !locked it will still generate a random color and not keep the same one